# create repo to install list of files using yum

Tags: json, linux, rpm, yum

Requirement: linux would be receiving activity to schedule the patches (mostly rpms). I am looking to create repo on activity with list of rpms. This is continues. When scheduled, the activity should run "yum install activity repo". The /etc/yum.repos.d/myrepo should be looking into scheduled activity repo.
The repo creation is based on activity json file, which has list of packageid and each package Id has 10 or more rpms. 
yum install to run on each packageid(list of rpms).

Once the activity is over, the corresponding repo should be deleted from list of repos currently in active list.

createrepo --pkglist, createrepo --groupfile - don't how to use it.

as when activity scheduled. corresponding repo to be created, when scheduled, yum install on repos should occur, 
usage of yum command and /etc/yum.repos.d/ is expected.

Comment: Will be their anyone interested to help me?

Comment: This question is probably to broad in it's current form: it doesn't look like you've tried solving this yourself, and the question seems to be asking us to do all the work.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you remove the repo after you install package from that repo? That would hinder other activities with yum.

Anyway, nothing such exists. Closest is [Red Hat Satellite](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/management/satellite) which allows you to create reports on server, group them and pass through the various environment (QE, staging, production) and to schedule updates.